Postgres UPDATE int[] column with values from jsonb column
I have a JSONB column with an array of integers and I'd like to migrate it to a native column of array of integers:
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN MyColumn TYPE int[] USING jsonb_array_elements(MyColumn)

However, this does not work:

set-returning functions are not allowed in transform expressions

MyColumn values look like this: [25,32].

(without a DB to test, a quick idea) Wouldn't creating a new temp jsonb column, copying MyColumn to it, emptying MyColumn, altering it, then updating the table with a set MyColumn = jsonb_array_elements(MyColumnCopy) then dropping MyColumnCopy, do it?

Since I didn't want to add a function for something so simple I did the following:
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN MyColumn TYPE int[] USING TRANSLATE(MyColumn, '[]', '{}')::int[]


Be aware this won't work for a text[] column which may have [] or {} in it.

I believe its because jsonb_array_elements returns a set of rows instead of single value. As mentioned in the comments , I tried a similar approach to create a new column and then updating the new column
Fiddle
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD COLUMN new_array_column int[];

UPDATE MyTable
SET new_array_column = (
    SELECT array_agg(elem::int)
    FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(MyColumn) AS elem
);

ALTER TABLE MyTable
DROP COLUMN MyColumn;

ALTER TABLE MyTable
RENAME COLUMN new_array_column TO MyColumn;

Output



id
mycolumn




1
{25,32}


2
{10,20,30}




jsonb_array_elements() returns a set of jsonb, not an array of integer. So twice incorrect.
You might use jsonb_array_elements_text() instead, cast to integer and aggregate that to an array, but that requires a subquery and ALTER TABLE does not allow that in the transform expression.
Solution
Create a tiny auxiliary function for the task:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonbarr_to_intarr(_js jsonb)
  RETURNS int[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
RETURN ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(_js)::int);

Then you can proceed with ALTER TABLE  as planned:
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN col TYPE int[] USING jsonbarr_to_intarr(col);

fiddle
See:

How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?

If you don't want to keep the function around, make it temporary:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.jsonbarr_to_intarr(_js jsonb) ...

See:

How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?

Note that ALTER TABLE is fundamentally different from UPDATE!
The former locks the whole table while doing a rewrite, which is much simpler and typically substantially faster. But blocking concurrent access must be avoided in some databases, especially if the table is huge, so it would take a long time. Then, incrementally populating a new column may be the way to go (even if that's a lot more complex and expensive overall).
